# why is my class being copied in the father automatically?

Tags: flutter, dart

What i wanted is to select a list of 'groupos' and to to do it i used a separate .dart with a dialog, as well i created a class to use as a model in another .dart.

So it works but not as i wanted becouse dosen't matter if i click outsithe the dialog or if i click in the buttons the information is going to the father anyway.

I don't get the logic, how the info go back? and how to avoid it?

[image]

```
////////////////////models.dart

class GroupList {
  List groupListId;
  List groupListName;
  GroupList(this.groupListId, this.groupListName);

  GroupList.clear() {
    groupListId = [];
    groupListName = [];
  }
}

////////////////////groupScreen.dart

GroupList groupList = GroupList.clear();


onTap: () async {
                  await groupsDialog(context, groupList);

                  setState(() {});
                },

////////////////////groupsDialog.dart

GroupList groupList;

Future groupsDialog(BuildContext context, _groupList) async { 
  groupList = _groupList;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (groupList.groupListId.contains(widget.id)) {
      boolValue = true;
    }
  }

onTap: () {
setState(() {
      boolValue = !boolValue;
      if (boolValue) {       
        groupList.groupListName.add(widget.name);
      } else {
        groupList.groupListName.remove(widget.name);
      }
    });
}
```

I would like to only save the class from the dialog if you click in 'guardar' if not just keep the values before open it.

Thanks